# Application of Leverage in Different Interest Rate Environments to an Efficient Portfolio

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, asset-allocation, leverage

I have read that some Institutional Investors are utilizing leverage.  According to Modern Portfolio Theory, to apply leverage one would:

a) find the tangency portfolio on the efficient frontier from the risk free rate and
b) leverage it up or down to attain the desired level of risk and target return

As a starting point, I assume that the 60:40 Equity:Fixed Income portfolio is the Capital Market portfolio and tangency portfolio, since many Institutional Investors use some version of this allocation currently.  I also assume that the risk reward characteristics of all investable assets have not changed.  In other words, expected return, volatility and correlation have remained the same.

I further assume that in applying leverage, such investors would borrow at the risk free rate and allocate to the tangency portfolio.

**Question 1:
Does the tangency portfolio change with the level of interest rates?**

The decision to apply leverage was made when the risk free interest rate was considerably lower than currently.  As such, this seems to imply that the point of tangency in that environment would be a portfolio that is lower in risk and return than with a higher interest rate.  As such, under the current 5% risk free rate, would the current tangency portfolio be something closer to 70:30, Equities:Fixed Income?

**Question2: Does it make sense to leverage such a portfolio?**

I understand that there are duration, convexity and credit differences between borrowing rates and a fixed income portfolio but if borrowing is considered a negative allocation to Fixed Income, would taking on such leverage essentially be moving the portfolio more toward equities?  At the extreme, if one were to apply 130% leverage, and apply it to a 70:30 portfolio, wouldn't one just be allocated to equities?  It should at least negate part of the risk free sovereign portion of the fixed income portfolio.  Also, does it make sense to apply leverage with an inverted yield curve (borrow at 5% and lend at 4%)?